# Is there a way to setup lifetime subscription for my Android app in Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

In Google Play Console, I have previously created yearly and monthly subscriptions and they work just fine, however now I want to create a subscription where the user only pays once and gets a lifetime subscription to the application.

Unfortunately, when I create a new subscription, it is required to select one "Renewal Type", which has the most a period of 1 year

How can I create a subscription, where the user only pays once and is never charged again?

[Google Play Console: Create New Subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mVn8.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would technically not fall into the Subscription category. A Subscription has to have recurrent billing. I see two potential solutions to your case:

1. You could go to the App Pricing page and set a price for your app there.
2. You can create an In-app product that would not expire.

I see an increasing number of developers using the second option. A good example would be Forest.

Comment: In the second option, how about the expiration period of the user's subscription? For example an month period or 1 year period. It lasts until the end of period even cancelled and it looks like I could not make purchase for the lifetime product if the subscription has not been finished. Could you show me how you handle this case?